# Create a New SubCategory LineStyle in Revit

Tags: c#, revit-api

I have created code that gathers a list of the existing "Line Styles" in Revit.

```
List<Category> All_Categories = doc.Settings.Categories.Cast<Category>().ToList();
Category Line_Category = All_Categories[1];
foreach (Category one_cat in All_Categories) { if (one_cat.Name == "Lines") { Line_Category = one_cat;} }
if (Line_Category.CanAddSubcategory)
{
      CategoryNameMap All_Styles = Line_Category.SubCategories; List<string> Line_Styles = new List<string>();
      foreach (Category one_category in All_Styles) { if (one_category.Name.Contains("CO_NAME")) {Line_Styles.Add(one_category.Name); } }
                TaskDialog.Show(Line_Styles.Count.ToString() + " Current Line Styles", List_To_Dialog(Line_Styles));
}
```

This gets the list of line styles, but when I try:
Category New_Line_Style = Line_Category.NewSubCategory....
Visual Studio tells me there is no definition for NewSubCategory

Can anyone tell me how to make a new SubCategory of "Lines", or what I'm doing wrong in the above code?

NOTE:  I discovered the main issue.  I was attempting to add the sub category to my variable Line_Category (which is itself a category, which should be a parent).  I had also attempted adding the sub category to All_Categories (which had been cast as a list and not a CategoryNameMap).

When I added a variable that was not cast, NewSubCategory became available.  However, now I am unable to see how to set the line pattern associated with my new style -- the only example I've found online suggests using New_Line_Style.LinePatternId, but that is not in the list of available options on my new SubCategory.  Is there some way to set the default pattern to be used when creating a new SubCategory?

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy Tammik wrote a post about retrieving all the linestyles here: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/08/retrieving-all-available-line-styles.html.  That might help explain some of the linestyle category stuff in more detail.

Here's another good link asking the same question and how it was solved using VB: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/08/retrieving-all-available-line-styles.html.  Here's a C# version of the VB code that worked for a new linestyle:

```
UIApplication app = commandData.Application;
UIDocument uidoc = app.ActiveUIDocument;
Document ptr2Doc = uidoc.Document;

Category lineCat = ptr2Doc.Settings.Categories.get_Item(BuiltInCategory.OST_Lines);
Category lineSubCat;
string newSubCatName = "NewLineStyle";
Color newSubCatColor = new Color(255, 0, 0);  //Red

try
{
  using (Transaction docTransaction = new Transaction(ptr2Doc, "hatch22 - Create SubCategory"))
  {
    docTransaction.Start();
    lineSubCat = ptr2Doc.Settings.Categories.NewSubcategory(lineCat, newSubCatName);
    lineSubCat.LineColor = newSubCatColor;
    docTransaction.Commit();
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.....however, I should have clarified that the last paragraph of my question was in fact a partial answer.  I was able to create line styles.  However, all my line styles, with whatever name they have, are mapped to line pattern SOLID.  I have been able to modify both the color and line weight, but this is all useless if I cannot also modify the line pattern.  Certainly I can modify these "by hand" after the fact, but this defeats most of the purpose of having a program able to create a series of line styles automatically, based on situation (concrete vs. steel) or client.